# R division by Zero

Tags: r, data.table, division, zero

This might be very simple, but I am not able to get how to fix this problem. Basically I need to calculate growth for multiple columns. So when I am dividing by  a column, if it has 0 value it returns **Inf**

Let me take a example data set

```
a <- c(1,0,3,4,5)
b <- c(1,4,2,0,4)
c <- data.frame(a,b)
c$growth <- b/a-1
```

So if you see for the 2nd row since a is having 0 the growth is Inf. It should display 4

My original data is in data.table so any solution in data.table would help.

How can we fix this?

Comment: What's the logic there? How does 4/0-1=0.4?

Comment: @MrFlick, thank you for pointing it out. It should be 4 (I have updated the same). So considering these values as price, we can say that the price has gone up 4 times.

Comment: Why it is `4` now? The unit in `growth` would be inconsistent for every rows by your logic.

Comment: If you truly want to do this, I think use `ifelse` will work: `c$growth <- ifelse(c$a == 0, c$b, c$b/c$a - 1)`

Comment: @ycw, yes the unit is consistent, consider an example where a=1 and b=5 then too we would have b/a-1 = 4, b has grown over a 4 times

Comment: @ycw, ifelse condition works.....I could not think of this simple logic :(

Comment: @user1412 I also learned the use of `ifelse` from others. Keep learning.

Comment: The data.table syntax is `DT[growth == Inf, growth := b]` or similar.

Comment: If you really have _exactly_ zero at the first point then no amount of growth can give a positive value at the second point. If you're defining growth as the _ratio_ between b and a (-1) then the correct answer for [a=0, b=4] is infinity. You seem to define growth as the ratio (-1) for non-zero initial, and as the arithmetic _difference_ for zero initial. Using two different definitions for the same term is a recipe for confusion unless you're very very careful in reporting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you want to turn Inf to 4. In my opinion it doesn't make any sense as the growth is not 4 is Inf. However, if you still want to do that here's some code:

```
a <- c(1,0,3,4,5)
b <- c(1,4,2,0,4)
data <- data.frame(a,b)
data$growth <- b/a-1
data[data$growth == Inf,3] <-  data[data$growth == Inf,2]
```

Comment: `which` is redundant here. You can remove `which`.

Comment: An advice to the OP. Since `c` is a function in R, it is better not to create a data frame with the name `c`.

Comment: that's correct, edited both the question and my answer so they are consistent to each other.

Comment: @dvarelas, I am getting the expected results basis this, but not clear with usage of ,3 and ,2. Could you please help understand this

Comment: that means replace the value of the third column by the value of the second column (for all the rows where Inf is in the third column)